# SDN4 is not returning nested Entities

Tags: java, spring-data-neo4j

Hello Stack overflow,

I have the following Problem:

I have these entity classes:

```
    public class UnknownEntity extends NetworkEntity{
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = UuidStrategy.class)
        private String id;

        @Override
        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Override
        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }
    }


    @NodeEntity
    public class NetworkEntity {

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Id
        protected String id;

        public List<NetworkInterfaceEntity> getInterfaces() {
            return interfaces;
        }

        public void setInterfaces(List<NetworkInterfaceEntity> interfaces) {
            this.interfaces = interfaces;
        }

        @Relationship(type = "is_composed_of")
        protected List<NetworkInterfaceEntity> interfaces ;
    }


@NodeEntity
public class NetworkInterfaceEntity {
    public String getInterfaceId() {
        return interfaceId;
    }

    public void setInterfaceId(String interfaceId) {
        this.interfaceId = interfaceId;
    }

    public String getIpAddress() {
        return ipAddress;
    }

    public void setIpAddress(String ipAddress) {
        this.ipAddress = ipAddress;
    }

    public String getNetmask() {
        return netmask;
    }

    public void setNetmask(String netmask) {
        this.netmask = netmask;
    }

    public String getMacAddress() {
        return macAddress;
    }

    public void setMacAddress(String macAddress) {
        this.macAddress = macAddress;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public InterfaceState getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(InterfaceState state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public List<NetworkInterfaceEntity> getSubInterfaces() {
        return subInterfaces;
    }

    public void setSubInterfaces(List<NetworkInterfaceEntity> subInterfaces) {
        this.subInterfaces = subInterfaces;
    }

    public long getBytesSent() {
        return bytesSent;
    }

    public void setBytesSent(long bytesSent) {
        this.bytesSent = bytesSent;
    }

    public long getBytesRecived() {
        return bytesRecived;
    }

    public void setBytesRecived(long bytesRecived) {
        this.bytesRecived = bytesRecived;
    }

    @Id
    private String interfaceId;
    private String ipAddress;
    private String netmask;
    private String macAddress;
    private String name;
    private InterfaceState state;
    @Relationship(type = "is_composed_of")
    private List<NetworkInterfaceEntity> subInterfaces;
    private long bytesSent;
    private long bytesRecived;


}
```

When I now try to query the UnknownEntities via a Neo4j Crud Repository with a custom @Query Method, the UnknownEntities wont be nested with the necessary NetworkInterfaceObjects, even tough my query returns these.

```
public interface UnknownEntityRepository extends CrudRepository<UnknownEntity,String> {
    @Query("MATCH (u:UnknownEntity)-[:is_composed_of]->(i:NetworkInterfaceEntity) WHERE i.ipAddress IN {0} WITH u as unknown MATCH p=(unknown)-[r*0..1]-() RETURN collect(unknown),nodes(p),rels(p)")
    List<UnknownEntity> searchMachinesByIp(List<String> ipAddresses);
}
```

In this particular case the NetworkInterfaceEntities do not contain more subInterfaces, so I only want the NetworkInterfaceEntities that belong the the UnknownEntity. But when I use this Query I only get UnknownEntities where the NetworkInterfaceList is null. I even tried different Querys to no avail for example: 
"MATCH p=(u:UnknownEntitie)-[:is_composed_of]-(n:NetworkInterfaceEntity) WHERE n.ipAddress in {0} RETURN collect(n),nodes(p),rels(p)".

My Question is, if what I want is even possible with SDN4 Data and if it is, how I can achieve this, Since my alternative is to query the database for every NetworkInterface separately, which I think is really ugly.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can't thank you enough!..Your question helped me solve an issue I was facing while fetching related nodes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try if returning the full path like this:

```
public interface UnknownEntityRepository extends CrudRepository<UnknownEntity,String> {
    @Query("MATCH (u:UnknownEntity)-[:is_composed_of]->(i:NetworkInterfaceEntity) WHERE i.ipAddress IN {0} WITH u as unknown MATCH p=(unknown)-[r*0..1]-() RETURN  p")
    List<UnknownEntity> searchMachinesByIp(List<String> ipAddresses);
}
```

works for your. If not, try naming the objects in question, i.e. `RETURN i as subInterfaces` works for you.

Are you using Spring Data Neo4j 4 or 5? If you're on 4, consider the upgrade to 5 to be on a supported level.

Please let me know, if this helps.

Comment: Hi Michael,actually I realized there was another problem in my code, that prevent the above solution from working. I t works for me now and I actually know howto generally get all the relationships I want when querying with sdn4. I actually think I am using  version 5.

Thank you for your suggestion though!